# How to force new window or tab in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, tabs, window

I am trying to open a new window or tab from my Silverlight application. 
How can I force the target type (window/tab)?
Right now, it's using the browser default settings when I call:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"), "_blank");
```

I am using context menu to do this and I would like to have the same results as in a regular browser, "Open in new tab" and "Open in new window".
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the following article regarding `HtmlPage.PopupWindow()`:

[How to Popup a Browser Window](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/09/30/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-52-how-to-popup-a-browser-window.aspx)

Also it is `blank` not `_blank` if using `Navigate`.

Alternatively you can always call a javascript function from Silverlight.  Create a function that takes a url paramater in javascript and then just call it from Silverlight like:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("OpenMyNewWindow", new string[] { "http://www.google.com" });
```

Javascript function:

```
function OpenMyNewWindow(url)
{
    window.open(url, "nameOfWindow");
}
```

This is the most cumbersome but it has lots of flexibility to do other stuff and possibly get the right feel for tab / window.  As for dictating a tab or window I don't think you can as that is specific to the browser and could be diff depending on which browser you are using.

Comment: link to microsoft blog is redirecting to **Download Silverlight**